# Can I use already written Jmh microbenchmarks to warm up production code

Tags: java, jmh

I have a number of benchmarks for code paths that need to be highly performant. The warm up iterations of my Jmh micro benchmarks are much more effecient than warm up code I've written to do this in production. My question, can I export my benchmarks and call them through the Java api, in order to warm up code paths in a real live application. Or is there some magic under the hood that would make this ineffective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend you to do so. First of all, it is not given that you can provide all the infrastructure that is needed to the benchmark. For example, it is impossible to provide certain objects such as `Blackhole` as this class cannot be instantiated from outside a benchmark. Second of all, there is no guarantee that the VM's warmup turns out as you intend: the real code might show a slightly different behaviour such that you benchmark rather pollutes your profile rather than prepares the VM for the *real world*.

In order to warm up the VM, it is almost always better to provide interaction from the outside that resembles the real interaction. Teaching a program to *self-warmup* is very fragile to code changes and almost never a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

I think launching the benchmarks via the API with 0 forks will run the benchmarks in the launching VM. If they constitute good warmup then you might get the effect you're after.